# AV1 video frame data format in Matroska/WebM Block

Tags: webm, mkv

As I know, H.264/H2.65 in MKV follows the sample format defined in ISOBMFF, the video frame data is like as:

```
|-- NALUnit length--|-- NALUnit data --|-- NALUnit length --|-- NALUnit data --|...
```

There is a document to show how AV1 frame data is stored in ISOBMFF (https://aomediacodec.github.io/av1-isobmff/), originally I think AV1 in MKV/WebM should follow it, but I found all AV1 webm files downloaded from internet do NOT follow it at all.

For example,
https://www.elecard.com/storage/video/140831_av1_720p_2700kbps.webm

```
00000000h: 82 87 88 93 06 86 00 9F E0 59 E8 30 E0 5F FF E3 ; ‚‡ˆ“.†.ŸàYè0à_ÿã
```

It is obviously not to follow AV1 sample format defined for ISOBMFF.

Anybody can give some information for it?

Answer (score 1):

The file provided in the question really seems to be invalid - even using the new ffmpeg 4.0 release (I took it from [zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)) which has added av1 support the decoder complains that the bitstream is corrupt. I also had a [toy webm player](https://github.com/rubu/WebMPlayer) that I used to verify webm files with vp8 that I made for live streaming. I patched it a bit to have av1 support but also there the decoder returns an error about invalid bitstream, so it seems that the file is just bad. Sadly the new ffmpeg 4.0 cuurently does not allow transcoding webm/vp8 to webm/av1 so I cannot test this on a valid file.

```
[libopus @ 000001f5f8b0c540] No bit rate set. Defaulting to 64000 bps.
[libaom-av1 @ 000001f5f8b0ac00] 0.1.0-9436-g8207b91f6
[webm @ 000001f5f8a604c0] Only VP8 or VP9 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): 
Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

Comment: Yes, it is very hard to find workable WEBM/MKV/MKV stream with AV1, and there is also no detailed spec to describe it, it is really confused for this open media

Comment: I think the spec is fine. The issue is that ffmpeg is unable to mux it (even though there aren't any obvious reasons for that).